# How to delete a table row in JS using a onclick event without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

```
const btnToDoInfo = document.getElementById("btnToDoInfo");
var arrayToDo = [];
btnToDoInfo.addEventListener("click", ToDoFunc);
function ToDoFunc()
{
    var ToDoTask = document.getElementById("Task-Dropdown").value;
    var ToDoModCode = document.getElementById("ModuleCode-Dropdown").value;
    var ToDoDescription = document.getElementById("Description").value;
    const d = new Date();
    let timeStamp = d.getTime();
    const arrayOfObjects = 
    [{TaskName: ToDoTask, ToDoModCode: ToDoModCode, Description: ToDoDescription ,UniqueID: timeStamp}]
    arrayToDo.push(arrayOfObjects);

    //Add task and Module to the table 
    var ToDoTable = document.getElementById("ToDo-Table");

    var rowCnt = ToDoTable.rows.length -1; 
   
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    row = ToDoTable.insertRow(rowCnt);
    row.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction(this)");
    console.log(row.attributes);

    var ModuleCodeRow = row.insertCell(0);
    var TaskRow = row.insertCell(1);
    var DescriptionRow = row.insertCell(2);
    var TimeRow = row.insertCell(3);
    TaskRow.innerHTML = ToDoTask;
    ModuleCodeRow.innerHTML = ToDoModCode;
    DescriptionRow.innerHTML = ToDoDescription;
}


function myFunction(x){
     var i = x.rowIndex
     document.getElementById("ToDo-Table").deleteRow(i); 
}
```

HTML
The following is my HTML for the specific table in question

```
<h1>To do list</h1>

<label for = "ModuleCode-Dropdown">Module Code</label>
<select name="Module-Codes" id = "ModuleCode-Dropdown"></select><br><br>


<label for = "Task-Dropdown">Task</label>
<select name="Task" id = "Task-Dropdown"></select><br><br>

<label for = "Description">Description</label>
<input type="text" id = "Description"><br><br>

<input type = "button" class = "add" id = "btnToDoInfo" value = "Add"><br><br>

<!--A table where the output is shown-->
<table class = "ToDo" id = "ToDo-Table">
    <tr>
        <th>Module Code</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id = "ModuleCode-Content"></td>
        <td id = "Task-Content"></td>
        <td id = "Description-Content"></td>
        <td id = "DueDate-Content"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I dynamically created table rows with a attribute of onclick but when I run the code I receive the following error

Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick. I cannot use jQuery.

I want the table row I click on to be deleted.

Comment: Could you share your HTML?

Comment: I added it for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an event listener to the row element as follows:

`row.addEventListener("click", myFunction);`

and change myFunction to:

```
function myFunction() {
  this.remove();
}
```

Comment: The following error occurs when I use addEventListener. Uncaught ReferenceError: row is not defined

Comment: That is strange. Such error would only occur if the setup code in ```ToDoFunc``` would be initialising ```row``` incorrectly. May I ask, does ```row.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction(this)");``` not throw an error?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentally removed any of your logic when copying my example? It should work if ```ToDoTable``` is defined and ```rowCnt``` is a number: 

```row = ToDoTable.insertRow(rowCnt);```

Comment: I have not changed any logic, and I don't believe row.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction(this)"); returns an error, but outside of the ToDoFunc block myFunction isnt seen.

Comment: Interesting, you can alternatively do this ```newRow.addEventListener('click', newRow.remove)```.
The core problem you have however is that ```row``` is ```undefined``` which I don't believe is caused by my code. Can I ask, does it work initially and then stop working when you delete multiple rows? When exactly does this error occur?

Comment: I moved var row = document.createElement("tr"); to the top outside the ToDoFunc and I no longer receive a error for addEventListener if I do so but I still receive my initial error Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick.

Comment: I got the code to work 100. Will post my answer soon. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

try finding the element and select it within a variable, for example:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#id');
```

and then remove it using:

```js
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: Where should I put this code?